# Recent rapid question upvotes

Tags: discussion, questions

i'm just wondering if anyone is noticing questions are upvoted very high, very fast. I'm not sure that there is an inherent issue with this.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think I've seen any new questions that are upvoted very high: https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=votes:15  At first glance, I think that looks normal.  The older questions have a lot of votes, but even the old ones really aren't high (at least by stackoverflow.com standards).

The 'very fast' upvotes could be users like me who always have the site open and sorted by new questions: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest  If the question is something that will be useful/helpful, I upvote it.  Just like I did with your question a few minutes ago ( [ArcGIS: Create a line layer from a point layer and csv data file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3730/arcgis-create-a-line-layer-from-a-point-layer-and-csv-data-file))!

Also, users with RSS feeds configured are notified of new questions relatively quickly (depending on the refresh rate).

Comment: I agree, seems normal, it feels like it follows the amount of views, higher views -> higher votes (usually), probably because the subject is interesting.

Comment: If we are to compare to stackoverflow, we should divide by number of visitors per day.  Anyway I have noticed very little downvoting.  As part of beta testing, perhaps we should deliberately post some dumb questions to see if they get downvoted.  If they don't, something needs correctng.  Any volunteers?

Comment: This is only a test : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3769/transhuman-geography-gis-or-games

Comment: oh no! +1 on the question, i assure you...that wasn't me!  maybe users look at your rep and assume you know what you are talking about? I wonder what would happen if a low-rep user posed a similar question?

Comment: Perhaps transhuman bots have slipped past the captcha. oh the transHumanity!

Comment: Right, my tongue was firmly in my cheek :)

Comment: I am now unable to delete my original post since it has been upvoted. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3769/transhuman-geography-gis-or-games This doesn't make sense to me.  There is only one answer and it has only one upvote, yet the message says there are "too many upvotes" to allow deletion.